# TypeScript type constraint expressing an optional parameter type that could exist at any position

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm looking to use method decorators combined with a parameter decorator.

```
class C {
  @method()
  f(a, b, @param c?: T, d?, e?) {
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make the `@method` decorator a typed descriptor that only accepts functions that have `c?: T` at **any** position in the function signature?

Right now I have something like:

```
const contexts = new WeakMap<object, number>();

function method() {
  return <F extends (...params: Array<any>) => any>(
    target,
    key,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<F>
  ): TypedPropertyDescriptor<F> => {
    console.log(contexts.get(target[key]));
    return descriptor;
  }
}

function param(
  target: Object,
  key: string | symbol,
  index: number
) {
  const method = target[key];
  contexts.set(method, index);
}
```

When I tried using tuple rest types, and used `T?` into it, it just accepted any function signature without problems.

```
[...any[], T?, ...any[]]
```

The main idea is to get TS to ensure that `@method` is not allowed on functions like:

```
class C {
  // Should be illegal
  @method()
  f(a, b, d?, e?) {
  }

  // Should be legal
  @method()
  g(a, b, @param c?: T, d?, e?) {
  }
}
```

What should `F` be to get such behaviour?

Comment: No, but if you provide the use case behind this maybe we can give alternatives.

Comment: you need this argument to be at any position - so typescript will not be able to help determine the type of any argument - you can just make it `(...args : any[]) => any;` - it's the same thing

Comment: There's a lot of implicit `any` in there, and no indication of what `T` or `@params` is.  Could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE?  Preferably using standard compiler options like `--strict`.

Comment: `T` could be `{ signal?: AbortSignal }`.

Comment: If you [edit] the code here to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE, I'll take another look.  Otherwise maybe someone else will come along?  Good luck!

Comment: I added more details. I don't have a reproducible example because the code doesn't work. This is a theoretical question about if `F` constraint can be expressed to limit the applicability of `@method` decorator.